# $5$ kids toss one die each. Find the number of ways that the sum of dice points is $22$.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I have already done these following steps and I'm already lost. Can someone please help me?

> $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 22$
>   when $1 \leq x_n \leq 6$ and $n = 1,2,3,4,5$.
>   Then, 
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x) & = (x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^5\\
> & = \left(\frac{x(1-x^6)}{1-x}\right)^5\\
> & = x^5 \cdot (1-x^6)^5 \cdot (1-x)^{-5}
> \end{align*}

Comment: What you have done thus far is correct.  You need to find the coefficient of $x^{22}$ in the expansion of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

By using mathematica, we have (already correct):
$$x^5(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^5$$
$$=x^5(x^{25}+5 x^{24}+15 x^{23}+35 x^{22}+70 x^{21}+126 x^{20}+205 x^{19}+305 x^{18}+420 x^{17}+540 x^{16}+651 x^{15}+735 x^{14}+780 x^{13}+780 x^{12}+735 x^{11}+651 x^{10}+540 x^9+420 x^8+305 x^7+205 x^6+126 x^5+70 x^4+35 x^3+15 x^2+5 x+1)$$
$$ = ... + 420x^{22}+ ...$$

so the answer is: 420

===================================================

Because:
$$f(x) = x^5+(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^5$$
$$=x^5[(1+x)(1+x^2+x^4)]^2$$
$$=x^5(1+x)^5[1+x^2(x^2+1)]^5$$

Note that degree of $x^k$ in $[1+x^2(x^2+1)]^5$ is even, odd degree term should be choosing from $(1+x)^5$, that is $x,x^3,x^5$, and corresponding term from $[1+x^2(x^2+1)]^5 $ is $x^{16},x^{14},x^{12}$

therefor:
$$[1+x^2(1+x^2)]^5 = 1+C_5^1x^2(1+x^2)+C_5^2x^4(1+x^2)^2+C_5^3x^6(1+x^2)^3+C_5^4x^8(1+x^2)^4+C_5^5x^{10}(1+x^2)^5$$
$$=......+ C_5^3C_3^1x^{12} + (C_5^4C_4^3+C_5^5C_5^2)x^{14}+(C_5^4C_4^4+C_5^5C_5^3)x^{16}+......$$

So, the answer is:

$$C_5^5 \cdot C_5^3C_3^1 + C_5^3 \cdot (C_5^4C_4^3+C_5^5C_5^2) + C_5^1 \cdot (C_5^4C_4^4+C_5^5C_5^3)$$
$$ = 420$$

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  We want the number of solutions to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 22$.

Comment: @wangwang: you forgot to take x^5 into account, so x^5 × (... + 420 ×  x^17 + ...) = ( ... + 420 × x^22 + ...)

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**  You correctly found that the generating function is 
$$f(x) = \frac{x^5(1 - x^6)^5}{(1 - x)^5}$$
We must find the coefficient of $x^{22}$.  By the Binomial Theorem,
$$(1 - x^6)^5 = 1 - 5x^6 + 10x^{12} - 10x^{18} + 5x^{24} - x^{30}$$
Hence, 
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = \frac{x^5(1 - 5x^6 + 10x^{12} - 10x^{18} + 5x^{24} - x^{30}}{(1 - x)^5}\\
     & = \frac{x^5 - 5x^{11} + 10x^{17} - 10x^{23} + 5x^{29} - x^{35}}{(1 - x)^5}
\end{align*}
If $n$ is a positive integer, then the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(1 - x)^{-n}$ is 
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{k} = \binom{n + k - 1}{n - 1}$$
Hence,
$$\frac{1}{(1 - x)^5} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{k + 4}{4} x^k$$
Therefore,
$$f(x) = (x^5 - 5x^{11} + 10x^{17} - 10x^{23} + 5x^{29} - x^{35})\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \binom{k + 4}{4} x^k$$
Notice that only the $k = 17, 11, 5$ terms contribute to the $x^{22}$ coefficient.  Therefore, the number of ways to obtain a sum of $22$ when five dice are thrown is 
$$\binom{17 + 4}{4} - 5\binom{11 + 4}{4} + 10\binom{5 + 4}{4} = 420$$

**Method 2:**  We can confirm this result by using the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

The number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_k = n$$
in the positive integers is 
$$\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$$
Hence, the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 22 \tag{1}$$
in the positive integers is 
$$\binom{22 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{21}{4}4$$
From these, we must exclude those solutions in which one or more of the variables exceeds $6$.  Notice that since $3 \cdot 7 + 2 = 23 > 22$, at most two of the variables may exceed $6$.

Suppose $x_1 > 6$.  Then $x_1' = x_1 - 6$ is a positive integer.  Substituting $x_1' + 6$ for $x_1$ in equation 1 and simplifying yields
\begin{align*}
x_1' + 6 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 & = 22\\
x_1' + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 & = 16 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the positive integers with 
$$\binom{16 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{15}{4}$$
solutions.  By symmetry, there are an equal number of solutions for each variable that could exceed $6$.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{15}{4}$$
solutions in which one of the variables exceeds $6$.

However, we have subtracted too much since we have subtracted those cases in which two of the variables exceed six twice, once for each of the ways we could have designated a particular variable as the one that exceeds six.  Since we only want to exclude these cases once, we must add them back.

Suppose $x_1, x_2 > 6$.  Then $x_1' = x_1 - 6$ and $x_2' = x_2 - 6$ are positive integers.  Substituting $x_1' + 6$ for $x_1$ and $x_2' + 6$ for $x_2$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x_1' + 6 + x_2' + 6 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 & = 22\\
x_1' + x_2' + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 & = 10 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation 3 is an equation in the positive integers with 
$$\binom{10 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{9}{4}$$
solutions.  By symmetry, there are an equal number of solutions for each of the $\binom{5}{2}$ ways we could select two variables to exceed six.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{5}{2}\binom{9}{4}$$
solutions in which two of the variables exceed six.

By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of ways the sum of the points on the five dice could equal $22$ is 
$$\binom{21}{4} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{15}{4} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{9}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

As with the other answers, here is an expansion of the generating function.
$$
\begin{align}
x^5\left(\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}\right)^5
&=x^5\sum_{j=0}^5\binom{5}{j}\left(-x^6\right)^j\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-5}{k}(-x)^k\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^5\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{j+k}\binom{5}{j}\binom{-5}{k}x^{k+6j+5}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^5\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^j\binom{5}{j}\binom{k+4}{k}x^{k+6j+5}\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^5\sum_{k=6j+5}^\infty(-1)^j\binom{5}{j}\binom{k-6j-1}{k-6j-5}x^k\tag{4}\\
&=\sum_{k=5}^\infty\color{#C00}{\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k-5}6\right\rfloor}
(-1)^j\binom{5}{j}\binom{k-6j-1}{4}}x^k\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: Binomial Theorem
$(2)$: combine and rearrange
$(3)$: $\binom{-5}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{k+4}{k}$
$(4)$: $k\mapsto k-6j-5$
$(5)$: change order of summation and $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$

For $k=22$, we get from the red part of $(5)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^2
(-1)^j\binom{5}{j}\binom{21-6j}{4}
&=\binom{5}{0}\binom{21}{4}-\binom{5}{1}\binom{15}{4}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{9}{4}\\[6pt]
&=420
\end{align}
$$